# Can Shutdown/Suspend/ be taken off the main menu in Unity?

Tags: shutdown, logout, administration

I tried to take a screenshot of the main manu power icon. My main goal is to have these actions on the login screen only, leaving the log out action as the mediator.

I'm currently using 16.04 64 bits

Comment: Are you using default Ubuntu desktop ?

Comment: @Serg yes certainly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The restart and shutdown items from the session indicator are controlled by `com.canonical.indicator.session` and its corresponding keys `suppress-restart-menuitem` and `suppress-shutdown-menuitem`. All you have to do is run two commands in terminal:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session suppress-restart-menuitem  true
```

and

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session suppress-shutdown-menuitem true
```

In 16.04 changes take effect immediately. I'm not sure about older version, so if you are running an OS prior to 16.04 you might want to log out and log back in to see changes.

[image]